# OpenLayers: How to make visible long lat of place after click on map from my partial code?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, latitude-longitude

I found [this](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch09-taking-control-of-controls/example-03.html) code for make visible EPSG:4326 gps after moving the mouse over the map. And I rewrite to html page with newest OpenLayers version.

But I need edit this small thing:
I prefer to make visible long lat coordinates, no EPSG:4326 coordinates as in the code. I tried to write long lat instead of GPS but it never gave me these coordinates.

I use OpenLayers version 6.

Rewrite code from page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="myposition"></div>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var osm_default = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [osm_default],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([-1.81185, 52.443141], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 6
        })
      });

      var mousePosition = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(2),
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        target: document.getElementById('myposition'),
        innerHTML: '&nbsp;'
      });

      map.addControl(mousePosition);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You appear to have two user accounts.  This makes curating your own question difficult, and increases work for those who have to review your edits.  See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to reconcile your logins

Comment: But this code displays `[long,lat]` coordinates. For example, for London you get something like `[0.14, 51.5]`. What's wrong with that? If you want projected `EPSG:3857` coordinates, just change `projection` option in `ol.control.MousePosition`.

Comment: If you want to show the position for clicks try this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/popup.html